# HANA Database deleting entries

Tags: sql, hana, apriori

Whenever I am using the Apriori algorithm from the PAL library in HANA, the database decides to delete entries from my dataset after a few minutes.

I am working on a project, where the Apriori Algorithm is used on a Dataset with about 40k entries. The Dataset was imported into HANA through a csv file.

First I created a table, which has the parameters for the Apriori algorith and a smaller table, which only uses the Transaction_ID and the item. Afterwards I use the CALL Apriori function from the PAL library to created an output.

I am having the following problem: Whenever I am using the Apriori algorithm, I am getting no results, even though I know, that there are some (Worked with it already with R) and after a few minutes the HANA database decides to delete all entries, that do not have the entry "Whole milk" in it.

I tested my code with a very small dataset (30 entries) and it works perfectly fine.

Does anyone know why that is the case? The SQL commands I am using are from the PAL library.

Answer (score 1):

This issue may related to the method you use to import data into hana.
Please make sure data was imported successfully and the table types should be as specified in this document (https://help.sap.com/docs/hana-cloud-database/sap-hana-cloud-sap-hana-database-predictive-analysis-library/apriori-apriori-7a073d6) before calling PAL procedure.
Apriori procedure itself will not delete any entry in input data table.